# Why are the widths of these HTML elements uneven?

Tags: html, css, width, display

I created some div elements and gave them the same width of 5px.

This is my CSS code:

```
div {
  background-color: black;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I was expecting all the divs to look the same, but some of them are 1px larger. Can anybody explain me why?

You can see the result [here](https://codepen.io/valerioio/pen/poONoVy).

Comment: @protob not an optical illusion, try to measure it by yourself

Comment: They are the same. If you see some of them wider, it's just an optical illusion. It's a bug in human perception not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I was also confused by the margin between the elements, I was not sure why it was there. I think the answer here is that is not the margin, but the whitespace between the divs rendered.

The width of the whitespace must not be a multiple of 1px, so there is some rounding that causes some whitespaces and some divs to be rendered 1px larger or smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is due browsers round off pixel values since browsers use whole numbers for pixel values. It may cause such errors sometimes. Maybe try using flex or grid
or you can try adjusting the width of your elements.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

They are all 5px, no element has a width of 6px in the codepen you provided:
[image: Codepen screenshot]